# NGINX: How to redirect all http / https requests to the main domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I'm trying to configure redirect on my Nginx server.

I only want to use the domain : example.com (no subdomain or www) with https.

Everything is fine with http but with https it only redirects www, so I have :

- http://example.com [redirect to] https://example.com
- http://www.example.com [redirect to] https://example.com
- http://foo.example.com [redirect to] https://example.com
- https://www.example.com [redirect to] https://example.com
- https://foo.example.com [no redirect] NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

In my sites-available/default file, I have two server blocks:

One to redirect request:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        listen          443 ssl;
        server_name     _;
        return          301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Server configuration:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name example.com;
        ...
}
```

I think my redirect server block is not configured properly for https, how can I correct the error?

Comment: The SSL certificate must be valid for the site **before** the redirect can take place. Which means that you need a wild card certificate to make this work. It's kind of Catch-22

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer. As I use let's encrypt for my certificate which doesn't support wildcard yet, I can't make a redirect for https subdomains.

Comment: One solution is to use separate `server` blocks for each subdomain, each with its own Let's Encrypt certificate.